# Vtiger CRM - Create a new custom view that extends master layout

Tags: view, vtiger

I'm creating a new custom view for existing module.
What I expected is the new custom view will have sidebard, header and footer natively, and the custom content will be inside the main content section.

I tried many ways but no lucky.
I event created a view that the same as List View, the display looks OK but the javascript does not work at all. The sidebar and buttons do not response to the click.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJbwi.png)

Please help me!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The JS file is link with the view so you should include your JS for your custom view.

In your custom view PHP file (which one is locate to modules/YourModule/views) you should add the function getHeaderScripts in order to include your JS file.

Comment: I viewed page source to compare with the the original ListView -> all script already loaded but it just doesn't work. Can you create a simple example repository that echo Hello World in the content section? Many thanks!